# Map extra column from stored procedure to Entity Framework code first model

Tags: linq, entity-framework, stored-procedures, ef-code-first, repository-pattern

I am using Entity Framework code first with a generic repository pattern with ASP.NET MVC. I have two tables `Category` and `Product`.

My model class of `product` is like this

```
  Public class Product
  {
     public int ProductID{get;set;}

     Public int CategoryID{get;set;}

     [ForeignKey("CategoryID")]
     public virtual Category Category{get;set;}

     [NotMapped]
     public string CategoryName{get;set;}
  }
```

The model is binding correctly as long as I am getting data using DBContext.

But I am having a problem when I am getting list of products from stored procedure mapped to `Product` object. So it is not mapping the `Category` property of `Product` object and hence I cannot able to get `Category.CategoryName`.

So I added a new property with `[NotMapped]` attribute in product class as `CategoryName`. But it is also not binding from stored procedure.

And if I remove the `[NotMapped]` attribute then it is correctly binding from stored procedure but error occurs again when getting product by `DbContext` (Linq).

Please help me in this regards.

Comment: How are you calling the SP?

Comment: _context.Database.SqlQuery<Product>(params...)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add an extra property, use the [`DbSet.SqlQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx) method for queries that return entity types. The returned objects must be of the type expected by the `DbSet` object, and *they are automatically tracked by the database context* unless you turn tracking off.

```
var products= _context.Products.SqlQuery("storedProcedureName",params);
```

The columns returned by SP should match the properties of your entity type otherwise, it will throw an exception.

After execute your SP, you should be able of get the `CategoryName` through your `Category` navigation property:

```
var catName=someProduct.Category.CategoryName;
```

---

On the other hand, the returned data by the [`Database.SqlQuery`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.Database.SqlQuery%60%601%28System.String,System.Object[]%29) isn't tracked by the database context, even if you use this method to retrieve entity types. If you want to track the entities that you get after execute your SP using this method, you can try this:

```
//Attach the entity to the DbContext
_context.Product.Attach(someProduct);

//The Category navigation property will be lazy loaded
var catName=someProduct.Category.CategoryName;
```

If you have disabled lazy loading you can load explicitly your navigation property:

```
//Load the Category navigation property explicitly
_context.Entry(someProduct).Reference(c => c.Category).Load();
```